# how to pass fetched data from a service to a different screen

Tags: flutter, dart

1. i have successfully fetched some data from API, which return a Json Array.
2. i have created promotions_page which it has a GridView.builder
3. Now i want to pass this fetched data to promotions_page.dart to PromotionCard() inside the itemBuilder.
4. how to pass the count to itemCount  of the GridView.builder

can someone please give some help. Thanks

```
**Promotions-api.dart which returns the fetched data**
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:buffet_dev_1/models/promotions_model.dart';

const key = {
  'APP-X-RESTAPI-KEY': "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
};

const API = 'http://111.111.11.1/project';

    fetchPromotions() async {
      final response = await http.get(API + '/promotion/all', headers: key);
      Result result = null;
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        result = resultFromJson(response.body);
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
      return result;
    }

**Promotions_page.dart**
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:buffet_dev_1/models/promotions_model.dart';
import 'package:buffet_dev_1/apis/promotion-api.dart';
import 'package:buffet_dev_1/widgets/w_promotion_card.dart';

class PromotionsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PromotionsPageState createState() => _PromotionsPageState();
}

class _PromotionsPageState extends State<PromotionsPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
        child: ListView(
          physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Акции',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontFamily: 'BuffetBold',
                      ),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () => print('Archive promotion pressed!'),
                      child: Text(
                        'Архив Акции',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontFamily: 'BuffetBold',
                          color: Colors.grey[400],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
                Container(
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      childAspectRatio: (45 / 35),
                      crossAxisCount: 1,
                    ),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: 2,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        PromotionCard(), // how to pass the data to this guy ?
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


WidgetCard page
w_promotion_card.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:buffet_dev_1/models/promotions_model.dart';
import 'package:buffet_dev_1/pages/promotion_details.dart';

class PromotionCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String image;

  PromotionCard(
      {this.id, this.title, this.description, this.image, this.promotion});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => PromotionDetails(
            promotions: null,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 10.0),
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(image),
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          border: Border.all(
            width: 1.5,
            color: Colors.grey[300],
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 170.0, 10.0, 10.0),
            child: Text(
              description,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                fontFamily: 'BuffetRegular',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FutureBuilder` for it:

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<Promotions>>(
  future: fetchPromotions(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return GridView.builder();
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
);
```

More information available in [Official Flutter Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).